# Laravel 5.4 ,variable "error" is not available in my view

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have noticed that when I try to use the laravel validator the error messages are not returned, I have read the documentation and verified that all the routes have the middleware "web" so the variable "$errors" should be available, however I have tested in all ways and I can not get it after a redirect, this is my code

RegisterController

```
$this->validate($request,[
            'nombre' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'apellido' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:ms_usuarios',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'g-recaptcha-response'=>['required',new Captcha],
            'terms_n_conditions'=>'required'
        ]);
    /*
 this code does not work either

$validator= Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'nombre' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'apellido' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:ms_usuarios',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'g-recaptcha-response'=>['required',new Captcha],
            'terms_n_conditions'=>'required'
        ]);*/
/*
 if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/register')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }*/
```

register.blade

```
@if (Session::get('errors'))
  <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-warning">
    <h4>Uwaga!</h4>
    <ul>
      @foreach (Session::get('errors')->all() as $error)
          <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
    </div>
@endif

       <!-- Here begins the registration form -->
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m12 l">
                    @if ($errors->any())

                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                     @endif
```

Comment: I'd check your kernal.php first to see what is loaded in your middleware group first

Comment: hi david, this is my route group 
`'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],`

Answer (score 0):

With the code shown I do not see `$errors` being set, it should be set to `$validator->messages()`

Comment: `$errors` is global, if the route is in the `web` middleware group, as defined in `Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php` and `app/Http/Middleware/Kernel.php`